# alertdialog read from xml and how put text to textview

Tags: android

So, I've an alertdialog that show me a list of elements:

```
<string-array name="numbers">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
        <item>four</item>
    </string-array>
```

this alertdialog read from sharedpreferences the value but I'd like write to textview not the value (1,2,3,etc) but the name from elements within xml:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("NUMBERS")

                    .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.numbers, (preferences.getInt("NUM", 9)), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            unitfiledownload = arg1;
                        }
                    })
```

my code works till here, now I need put the value of array in xml to textview:

```
textView.setText(""+""+preferences.getInt("NUM",0));
```

the line above (correctly) write to textview the value (like 1 or 2, etc).

how put to text view the number like "one or two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

```
String text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers)[preferences.getInt("NUM",0)]
```

The above code will return the string to the int on your preferences. To set the textview to it's value just to `textView.setText(text);`

You will probably have to subtract 1 to the index since you don't have the "zero" string.